# Изображения вокруг круглой кнопки

Tags: swift

У меня есть круглая кнопка, я хочу вокруг нее выстроить картинки, когда размер просто подгоняю, у меня при смене девайса звездочки оказываются не в том месте, может можно как-то привязать их к объекту?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот как сейчас код написан:

```
import SpriteKit 
class GameScene: SKScene, SKPhysicsContactDelegate {
var RestartBa : UIButton!
override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {
let Zvezda1 = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed:"10")
Zvezda1.position = CGPointMake(view.frame.size.width / 1.15, view.frame.size.height / 0.69)
Zvezda1.size = CGSize(width: 50, height: 50)
self.addChild(Zvezda1)

let Zvezda2 = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed:"10")
Zvezda2.size = CGSize(width: 50, height: 50)
Zvezda2.position = CGPointMake(view.frame.size.width / 0.91, view.frame.size.height / 0.69)
self.addChild(Zvezda2)

let Zvezda3 = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed:"10")
Zvezda3.size = CGSize(width: 50, height: 50)
Zvezda3.position = CGPointMake(view.frame.size.width / 1.42, view.frame.size.height / 0.66)
self.addChild(Zvezda3)

let Zvezda4 = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed:"10")
Zvezda4.size = CGSize(width: 50, height: 50)
Zvezda4.position = CGPointMake(view.frame.size.width / 0.79, view.frame.size.height / 0.66)
self.addChild(Zvezda4)

let Zvezda5 = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed:"10")
Zvezda5.size = CGSize(width: 50, height: 50)
Zvezda5.position = CGPointMake(view.frame.size.width / 1.55, view.frame.size.height / 0.62)
self.addChild(Zvezda5)

let Zvezda6 = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed:"10")
Zvezda6.size = CGSize(width: 50, height: 50)
Zvezda6.position = CGPointMake(view.frame.size.width / 0.75, view.frame.size.height / 0.62)
self.addChild(Zvezda6)

let Zvezda7 = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed:"10")
Zvezda7.size = CGSize(width: 50, height: 50)
Zvezda7.position = CGPointMake(view.frame.size.width / 1.42, view.frame.size.height / 0.584)
self.addChild(Zvezda7)

let Zvezda8 = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed:"10")
Zvezda8.size = CGSize(width: 50, height: 50)
Zvezda8.position = CGPointMake(view.frame.size.width / 0.79, view.frame.size.height / 0.584)
self.addChild(Zvezda8)

let Zvezda9 = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed:"10")
Zvezda9.size = CGSize(width: 50, height: 50)
Zvezda9.position = CGPointMake(view.frame.size.width / 1.15, view.frame.size.height / 0.56)
self.addChild(Zvezda9)

let Zvezda10 = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed:"10")
Zvezda10.size = CGSize(width: 50, height: 50)
Zvezda10.position = CGPointMake(view.frame.size.width / 0.91, view.frame.size.height / 0.56)
self.addChild(Zvezda10)

let size: CGFloat = 35.0
RestartBa = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: view.frame.size.width / 7, height: 60))
RestartBa.setTitle("1", forState: UIControlState.Normal)
RestartBa.setTitleColor(UIColor.greenColor(), forState: UIControlState.Normal)
RestartBa.frame = CGRectMake(view.frame.size.width / 2.6, view.frame.size.width / 4.2, 70, 70)
RestartBa.layer.cornerRadius = 35
RestartBa.layer.borderWidth = 2.0
RestartBa.layer.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor().CGColor
RestartBa.layer.borderColor = UIColor.greenColor().CGColor
self.view?.addSubview(RestartBa)

scene?.backgroundColor = UIColor.grayColor()
physicsWorld.contactDelegate = self
self.scene?.size = CGSize(width: 640, height: 1136)
}
```

Comment: Предположу. что `view.frame` на разных устройствах разный. А почему нельзя через синусы/косинусы от центра посчитать?

Comment: С математикой туговато, не очень понимаю как это прописать

Answer (score 1, accepted):

это не ответ на заданный вопрос, но все таки. Вот как примерно написать подсчет координат через син/кос

```
let numberOfImages = 10 //количество звезд
let center: CGPoint = CGPointMake(160, 200) // точка, относительно которой рисуются звезды
let distanceFromCenter:Double = 100 //расстояние от точки центра до звезды

for var i = 0; i < numberOfImages; i++ {
    let angle = M_PI*2/Double(numberOfImages)*Double(i)
    let view = UIImageView(image: UIImage(named: "star"))
    view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 40, 40)
    view.center = CGPointMake(center.x+CGFloat(distanceFromCenter*cos(angle)), center.y+CGFloat(distanceFromCenter*sin(angle)))
    self.view .addSubview(view)
}
```