# Как разместить изображения полукругом вокруг кнопки?

Tags: swift

Ранее я задавал вопрос про то, [как разместить изображения вокруг кнопки](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/482365/).
А можно ли их разместить полукругом? Уже всяко пробовал формулу поменять, не получается, или это как-то вообще по другому прописывается?

```
let numberOfImages = 10 //количество звезд
let center: CGPoint = CGPointMake(160, 200) // точка, относительно которой рисуются звезды
let distanceFromCenter:Double = 100 //расстояние от точки центра до звезды

for var i = 0; i < numberOfImages; i++ {
    let angle = M_PI*2/Double(numberOfImages)*Double(i)
    let view = UIImageView(image: UIImage(named: "star"))
    view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 40, 40)
    view.center = CGPointMake(center.x+CGFloat(distanceFromCenter*cos(angle)), center.y+CGFloat(distanceFromCenter*sin(angle)))
    self.view .addSubview(view)
}
```

[image: Вот так получается]
[image: А вот так хочу]

Хочу как на второй картинки

Comment: А хоть что-то получается? Картинка, пусть и кривокосая есть?

Comment: какие именно пол круга? если нижние, то ответ ниже, если что то другое, то напишите что именно надо

Answer (score 1, accepted):

вот так дополнить:

```
let numberOfImages = 4
let distanceFromCenter:Double = 100
let center: CGPoint = CGPointMake(160, 200)
let startAngle: Double = 50 // угол начала
let endAngle: Double = 150 // угол конца
let startAngleRad: Double = startAngle*M_PI/180
let endAngleRad: Double = endAngle*M_PI/180

for var i = 0; i < numberOfImages; i++ {
    let angle = ((endAngleRad-startAngleRad)/Double(numberOfImages)*Double(i))+startAngleRad
    let view = UIImageView(image: UIImage(named: "star"))
    view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 40, 40)
    view.center = CGPointMake(center.x+CGFloat(distanceFromCenter*cos(angle)), center.y+CGFloat(distanceFromCenter*sin(angle)))
    self.view .addSubview(view)
}
```

- Угол окончания должен быть больше, чем угол начала.
- 0 градусов справа на окружности, и увеличивается по часовой.

Comment: спасибо за быстрые ответы

Answer (score 1):

Пока что, можете `let angle = M_PI/Double(numberOfImages)*Double(i)` так поправить. Полукруг - это ведь пол круга, половина пи.

Comment: Так я пробовал, оно получается криво немного... Выше приложил картинки