# 2 изображения вокруг кнопки

Tags: swift

Ранее задавал вопрос про то, как разместить изображения вокруг кнопки, мне помогли [Как разместить изображения полукругом вокруг кнопки?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/483759/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%83%D0%BA%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%BC-%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BA%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B3-%D0%BA%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%BA%D0%B8)
Но возникла такая сложность, когда делаю 2 звезды размещается не так, как надо

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Нужно так: (но не понимаю как формулу поменять)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: покажите ваш код на данном этапе.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Положение первой звезды, это начальный угол. Вторая звезда будет "равномерно распределена" между начальным и конечным углами. то есть если например надо чтоб первая была на 70 градусов, а вторая на 110 (обе на 20 градусов от вертикали, написать надо так:

```
let startAngle: Double = 70 // угол начала
let endAngle: Double = 150 // угол конца
```

Comment: вот как, спасибо за объяснение

Comment: @PRKan упрощу вам жизнь немножко. если угол считать по вот такой формуле `let angle = ((endAngleRad-startAngleRad)/Double(numberOfImages-1)*Double(i))+startAngleRad` то последняя звезда будет точно на endAngle. помните, что если таким образом заполнять целую окружность, то первая и последняя лягут друг на друга.